# How is a web hosting service created?

Tags: web, hosting

I am a freshman Computer Science student. I would appreciate if some of you guys could help me understand the process of creating a web hosting service and explain how it works. Thank You. This question is my first; if I made mistakes, I  look forward to positive criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is a simple and straightforward question, the answer can be far from it. There are several different categories of a web hosting service. Your typical "Godaddy, HostGator, Bluehost" shared web hosting service is the most common one, but there are also Amazon's AWS or Digital Ocean that focus on Virtual Private Servers and there are also web hosting companies with a strong added value such as a website builder (like Squarespace, Weebly or Wix).

A web hosting is often (especially shared hosting) combined with a powerful control panel (cPanel and Plesk have most users) which allow you to create additional addon domains, subdomains, email addresses, MySQL databases, FTP accounts and many other simple and complex features. It goes so far that cPanel combined with Fantastico offers automatic (few clicks) Wordpress and Joomla installation among many CMS systems. No need to manually upload files, create databases, etc.

If you are looking to start a shared web hosting business yourself, you have to go one level above. For example, above cPanel is WHM. You can look at WHM like a very powerful software that helps you monitor active processes on servers, create new web hosting resellers, new web hosting accounts, track CPU activity and many other functions. Now account creation, termination and suspending is easier and almost automated with additional systems like WHMCS.

WHMCS is an entirely different system that is installed on a single domain on a server. WHMCS besides from account creation and termination allows web hosting clients to open support tickets, register domain names, purchase and automatically create web hosting accounts, and manage their account in general. In WHMCS, you cannot create email address, subdomains and other cPanel functionality.

With web hosting, there are several products and services that go hand in hand. I've already mentioned website builders, Content Management Systems and domain names. But there are also SSL certificates, various analytics services, web shops and other products that are installed on millions of websites.

When you are managing a server that offers shared hosting, dedicated hosting or reseller hosting you need to pay attention to load averages (CPU usage), downtime (99.99%) email blacklisting, hacks, phishing attempts, virus injections, holes in various widgets installed on websites and other threats that come your way on a daily basis.

This is just scratching the surface, but it's a step in a right direction in understanding the overview of a small web hosting company.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It gave me a clear picture of web hosting services!

Answer (score 1):

- You want to become a web host?
- Just check out which all hosting services you want to provide
- Research about Shared hosting, VPS hosting, Reseller hosting
- check which all latest technologies can be used to create these services.
- study how to setup and handle the activities.

Answer (score 1):

web hosting is easy to create,
you need some requirement,

first is hardware requirement,
second is proper ISP bandwidth
you need more uploading speed again downloading speed,

because if request come out to your server service and all page or data send to client,
so require high uploading speed,

first thing is hardware requirement.
you need proper storage device,
with auto backup system,
do you need good ram capacity,

if your system is low speed all clients face slow speed,
in this case bandwidth not work,
Yara ISP provide 1gbps speed but your system process data only 200 MB to 300 MB so that all data useless